# julia HTTP.WebSockets.open() timeouts not working

Tags: julia

Neither of the timeouts for HTTP.WebSockets.open() work.  I expect the connect timeout to timeout when the internet is down and it cant connect, and idle timeout to timeout when its actively connected and the internet goes down.

```
    using HTTP.WebSockets

    url = "wss://api.gemini.com/v1/multimarketdata?symbols=ETHUSD&top_of_book=true"

    WebSockets.open(url;
                connect_timeout=10, # stop trying after n seconds 
                idle_timeout=10, # disconnect after no messages for n seconds
                keepalive=true # should auto disconnect but doesn't
    )
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or is this a bug?